# Laravel 8 Missing required parameters for [Route: shop.show] [URI: {language}/shop/{shop}]

Tags: php, laravel, localization, parameter-passing, laravel-8

I have the error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: shop.show] [URI: {language}/shop/{shop}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\frile\resources\views\inc\header.blade.php)

I think I understand my problem but I'm not sure.

I'm trying to go to a detailpage of my product via a resource route. This works fine if I don't have my language switcher on it.

My language switcher needs the current routename so he can add eather 'en' or 'nl' in front of it. but my resource route 'shop.show' needs a parameter, and the switcher can't give it to him.

Is there a workaround? This is my code:

Routes:

```
Route::redirect('/', '/en');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {

   /* pages */
   Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index']) -> name('home');
   /* shop is in the products section */
   Route::get('/projects', [PagesController::class, 'projects']) -> name('projects');
   Route::get('/about', [PagesController::class, 'about']) -> name('about');
   Route::get('/contact', [PagesController::class, 'contact']) -> name('contact');

   /* products */
   Route::resource('shop', ProductController::class);
});
```

Controller (i'm giving the parameter product with it so my language switcher doesn't freak out):

```
public function show($product, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    return view('pages.shop.product', [app()->getLocale(), 'product' => $product]);
}
```

header.blade.php (where my language switcher is):

```
<header>
<h1><a href="{{ route('home', app()->getLocale()) }}">FRILE</a></h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ route('shop.index', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.shop') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('projects', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.projects') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('about', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.about') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('contact', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.contact') }}</a></li>
        <ul id="languageSwitcher">
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">en</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'nl') }}">nl</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

shop.blade.php (where my link to the detailpage is):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

   <h2>shop</h2>
   <a href="{{ route('shop.create', app()->getLocale()) }}">create product</a>

   @if (count($products) > 0)
       @foreach ($products as $product)
           <p><a href="{{ route('shop.show', [app()->getLocale(), $product -> id]) }}">{{ $product -> name }}</a></p>
       @endforeach
       {{ $products->links() }}
   @else
       <p>No products yet</p>
   @endif

@endsection
```

Middleware of setLanguage:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale($request->language);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ...  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes  pay attention to the associative array that is being passed to the `route` helper, you should try and follow this

Answer (score 0):

According to your show method, you are accepting two parameters, $product and $id, remove the $product from the show method, because you did not specify what it will do in the function and you did not pass it to the view, I think that is the issue, you can leave it this way

```
public function show ($id) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work, my app thinks I need to give a second parameter because of the language switcher, I've tried it already. I still get the same error. Thank you for answering tho.

Answer (score 0):

Oke so i did it in kind of a bad way, I just set an isset and empty value in my header.blade.php, It work's but if someone knows a better answer, lmk.

header.blade.php:

```
<header>
<h1><a href="{{ route('home', app()->getLocale()) }}">FRILE</a></h1>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ route('shop.index', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.shop') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('projects', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.projects') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('about', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.about') }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('contact', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('nav.contact') }}</a></li>
        <ul id="languageSwitcher">
            @isset($product)
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['en', $product->id]) }}">en</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['nl', $product->id]) }}">nl</a></li>
            @endisset
            @empty($product)
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">en</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'nl') }}">nl</a></li>
            @endempty
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing extra parameter, like:
Shop.blade.php file=>

```
<p><a href="{{ route('shop.show', [app()->getLocale(), $product -> id]) }}">{{ $product -> name }}</a></p>
```

use app()-.getLocale() as second parameter:

```
<p><a href="{{ route('shop.show', [$product ->
id,app()->getLocale()]) }}">{{ $product -> name }}</a></p>
```

Maybe it'll works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I searched online for almost 3h before analyzing the problem when it was really simple to solve.

Just verify if you have the **app()->getLocale()** for all the route instances like:

```
{{ route('password.update', app()->getLocale() ) }}
```